# Get multiparts from request and attach them to javax email in mobilefirst adapter

Tags: servlets, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

As pointed in DeveloperWorks, there is no support to multipart in adapters, but I'm still searching for anyway to get that data.

Here is my scenario:
The application is a native swift app, and it creates a request with the attachment files in multipart, and the parameters in POST. I have an adapter that receives that request, I'm able to get the parameters and send emails, but I cann't find a way to get the file from that request and attach it to the email. If I use:

```
var clientRequest = WL.Server.getClientRequest();
clientRequest.getParts();
```

I get an exception from the framework that says that multiparts is not supported by mobilefirst.

What I'm doing is to pass to a java class the complete request, but if I try to get the parts from java code, I also get the same exception.

My java class to send emails is working fine with attachments, what I'm not able to do is to get the file from the multipart request.
Any idea or suggestions? 
At this moment I'm gonna implement a base64 string to handle the file, but that will require that the app development team change code, and that's what we are trying to avoid.
Thansk a lot for your support guys.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in looking at the new Java Adapters launched in MobileFirst Platform 7.0. With that you can send whatever content you want and have more control in the adapter implementation. As stated in the documentation, you have:
"Ability to fully control the URLs structure, the content types, the request and response headers, content and encoding."

Basically your adapter will be fully implemented in Java.

More details at:

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/java-adapter/

and

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_overview_of_ibm_java_adap.html

EDIT:
With 6.3 I don't see any other way different than converting to base64 string.

Comment: Of course I'm going to review these links, but my actual implementation must be in 6.3, thanks for your answer.